# Can't register my custom package's dependency in Laravel5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, package-development

I am developing a blog as a custom package for Laravel 5.3.

So far I have got the routes, controller, models and migrations working.

I am now working on the CRUD. For the forms I thought I could use this:
https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html

---

**UPDATE**

I have installed the package with composer. The dependency is in the composer.json file. The files are in my package's vendor folder.
I have also tried to run

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

From my composer.json

```
"require": {
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.3.*"
 }
```

---

I have looked everywhere and people suggest to do the following:

```
/**
 * Register bindings in the container.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    // Bind the app.
    $this->app->bind('blog', function ($app) {
        return new Blog;
    });

    // Register LaravelCollective Form Builder.
    $this->app->register('Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider');
    $this->app->alias('Form', 'Collective\Html\FormFacade');
    $this->app->alias('Html', 'Collective\Html\HtmlFacade');
}
```

I currently get the following error everywhere:

> FatalThrowableError in Application.php line 610:
>   Class 'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found

Really not sure where I am going wrong.

---

**UPDATE**

I have tried bind instead of register:

`$this->app->bind('Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider');`

But this time I get the following error:

> Class 'Collective\Html\FormFacade' not found

---

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `composer.json` contains the dependency `laravelcollective/html`, if not, add it to your `composer.json` or include it via the following command `composer require laravelcollective/html`

Comment: Hi, yes I have, sorry forgot to add that I didn't know how to edit the post. I have added it as a comment above.

Comment: Have you tried running `composer dump-autoload -o`?

Comment: @RevalGovender is the dependency within your `"require": {` section in your `composer.json`?

Comment: Hi Ryan, yes it is:

"require": {
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.3.*"
  }

Comment: Remove the following:
`$this->app->register('Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider');
$this->app->alias('Form', 'Collective\Html\FormFacade');
$this->app->alias('Html', 'Collective\Html\HtmlFacade');`
& then run `composer update`, then add them back in and run your app.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've added the dependency to providers and aliases in `config/app.php`

```
'providers'=>[
     Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
 ],

'aliases'=>[
      'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
      'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
 ],
```

Comment: This will not work. I am developing a custom package. I have a composer.json and the vendor files within my package folder. So adding something to the config/app of the main application will not work.